# How to handle saved payment method that is about to expire?

Tags: payment

A customer may have a saved payment method (for convenience, recurring payments, etc.). What is the best way to prompt a user to add a replacement?

I've tried to google for examples but because every payment form has "card expiration date", I've field due to the "needle in a haystack" problem.

Is there a design pattern for that at all (like there are patterns for saving a payment method)? This seems to me as an edge-case problem that thousands upon thousands of businesses would have and, perhaps, there is a well-established practice to handle that kind of situation.

Comment: Do you have mocks showing your efforts, ideas and context so far? What is the domain, and where are you trying to introduce this? The more details, context and constraints, the more useful the question (and its answers from the community) can be helpful to you and others in a similar situation.

Comment: @MikeM the bottom line of my question is - is there a design pattern for that at all (like there are patterns for saving a payment method)? Because, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Only if I'll find out that there isn't I will devise something of my own. This seems to me as an edge-case problem that thousands upon thousands of businesses would have. And I haven't encountered a solution to that yet only because I change my cards sooner than they expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user will experience degraded service unless the credit card on file is up-to-date, your system needs to warn them starting 2-4 weeks before their next charge date. Consider an [on-screen alert](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/indicators-validations-notifications/) when they log in, with a link to the page where they can update the card.

Mint's alert lets users know that they need to promptly interact with the system in order for things to keep working properly:

[image: Mint alert notification]

Also consider an outreach notification via email or SMS, for users who might not log in frequently.

If the user won't experience anything particularly harmful by having an expired credit card on file, you can display the notification when they make their next credit card transaction, on the payment check-out screen.